# Ошибка can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Помогите пжл разобраться в ошибке. 
У меня есть DataFrame. Вот пример: 
[image: DataFrame]

Есть массив:

[image: Массив]

Я хочу вывести все строки DataFrame, в которых в столбце 'Skill' нету значений из массива. 
Делаю это так:

```
for i in df_skills_one['Skill']:
    for k in i:
        if k not in arr_bi:
            print(df_skills_one['Skill'][i:i+1])
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-260-dacb19ab97fd> in <module>
      2     for k in i:
      3         if k not in arr_bi:
----> 4             print(df_skills_one['Skill'][i:i+1])

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Помогите пжл разобраться в чем проблема и как избежать ошибки.
Спасибо

Comment: не стоит приводить исходные данные в виде картинок, и ваш код воспроизвести невозможно, и чтобы свой написать, надо делать модельные данные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример исходного DataFrame:

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({
                  "Skill":[("data","working"), ("business","work"), ("machine","learning","science")], 
                   "Freq":[100,200,300]})

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
                          Skill  Freq
0               (data, working)   100
1              (business, work)   200
2  (machine, learning, science)   300

In [21]: arr_bi = ["machine","learning","work"]
```

---

Решение:

```
In [22]: pat = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join(arr_bi))

In [23]: pat
Out[23]: '\\b(?:machine|learning|work)\\b'

In [24]: res = df[~df["Skill"].map(";".join).str.contains(pat)]

In [25]: res
Out[25]:
             Skill  Freq
0  (data, working)   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, как хранятся данные, вот этот код работает:

```py
# входные данные в виде словаря id:data[id]
cortage = {
  'id1' : {
    'skill' : ('data',),
    'freq' : 7620
  },
  'id2' : {
    'skill' : ('machine','data',),
    'freq' : 7620
  },
  'id3' : {
    'skill' : ('learning',),
    'freq' : 7620
  },
  'id4' : {
    'skill' : ('work',),
    'freq' : 7620
  },
}

# массив скиллов, записи с которыми исключаем
arr = [
  'data',
  'apple',
  'learning'
]
```

Решение задачи

```py
# создаём словарь-результат
result = {
  # он состоит из пары ключ:значение
  key : cortage[key]
  # которые берутся из словаря данных
  for key in cortage
  # если список скиллов, которые входят в массив исключаемых, не имеет элементов
  if [
    # формируем этот самый список скиллов из значений skill
    skill
    # которые берём из поля 'skill' текущей записи
    for skill in cortage[key]['skill']
    # только если она есть в массиве
    if skill in arr
  # если массив таких скиллов имеет длину 0, в нём нет исключаемых скиллов
  ].__len__() == 0
}

# проверяем вывод
for key in result:
  print(key,result[key])
```

Для этих входных данных я получил такой вывод:

```
id2 {'skill': ('machine',), 'freq': 7620}
id4 {'skill': ('work',), 'freq': 7620}
```

Если исходные данные хранятся не в виде словаря, а в виде массива/кортежа - напиши в комментариях, подредактирую, если нужна помощь

## UPDATE

Исходя из полученного примера хранения данных, задачу можно решить теми же генераторами, если перевести DataFrame в Dict, обработать и преобразовать обратно:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "Skill": [
    ("data","working"), 
    ("business","work"), 
    ("machine","learning","science")
  ], 
  "Freq":[
    100,
    200,
    300
  ]
})

arr = [
  'data',
  'apple',
  'learning'
]

# превращаем DataFrame в Dict
data_dict = df.to_dict()

# создаём список ID записей, которые нужно оставить (по тому же принципу, что и раньше)
keylist = [
  key
  for key in data_dict['Skill']
  if len([
      item
      for item in data_dict['Skill'][key]
      if item in arr
    ]) == 0
]

# формируем словарь результата на основании списка ID записей
result_dict = {
  'Skill' : [
    data_dict['Skill'][skill]
    for skill in keylist
  ],
  'Freq' : [
    data_dict['Freq'][freq]
    for freq in keylist
  ]
}

# превращаем результат в DataFrame
result = pd.DataFrame(result_dict)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Помогите пжл разобраться в чем проблема

Похоже, в строке `print(df_skills_one['Skill'][i:i+1])` вы к кортежу (tuple) `i` прибавляете 1.

Пример:

```
In [11]: ('data',) + 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-4d7ea34a9f89> in <module>
----> 1 ('data',) + 1

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Еще одно решение:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
              Skill  Frequency
0           (data,)       7620
1  (business, work)       2397
2     (experience,)       2312

In [5]: arr_bi
Out[5]: ['data', 'work', 'learning', 'computer']

In [6]: df.loc[df['Skill'].apply(lambda x: all(item not in arr_bi for item in x))]
Out[6]: 
           Skill  Frequency
2  (experience,)       2312
```

Здесь с помощью [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) применяем к столбцу `Skill` функцию, которая проверяет наличие элементов из каждого кортежа в списке `arr_bi` и возвращает `True` в том случае, если ни один элемент кортежа не входит в `arr_bi`.

```
In [7]: df['Skill'].apply(lambda x: all(item not in arr_bi for item in x))
Out[7]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: Skill, dtype: bool
```

Передаем эту последовательность булевых значений в [`loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) и получаем из датафрейма нужные нам строки. Можно записать так:

```
In [8]: m = df['Skill'].apply(lambda x: all(item not in arr_bi for item in x))

In [9]: df.loc[m] 
Out[9]: 
           Skill  Frequency
2  (experience,)       2312
```